Play a Video from a SFTP server in Unity Video Player
I am trying to load a video in the Unity VideoPlayer via url.
However this URL is a sftp url (e.g. sftp://ClientSFTP@sftp.hostname.eu/Directory/Directory/Video.mp4)
When I put in the url in the unity video player and enter play mode, I get these errors:

WindowsMediaFoundation received empty file
VideoPlayer cannot play url

I am well aware that sftp requires authentification and I planned on making a script that would log in and then get the urls to play them in the video player.
If you know any other way to store a file and access it without authentification I would very much appreciate if you told me about it !
I tried changing the permissions of the file and directories but they were reverted as soon as I changed them.

Most likely URL actually means a web page at most, not any arbitrary URL for any random protocol. Download the file to a temporary location and play the file locally instead.
